# CakePHP way to group data by months from SQL

Tags: sql, cakephp

For Example I have tables - Orders1, Orders2, Orders3, Users.

I need to make monthly and quartaly reports for each user. For example I am creating a function in Orders1 model `quartal_sum_by_users($users, $quarter)`. then I make something like this:

```
$cost = 0;
foreach($users as $user) {
  while($month <= 3) { // first three months
    $orders = $this->Order1->find('all', array(
      'recursive' => -1,
      'fields' => array('DISTINCT id', 'COALESCE(cost+work_cost+work_installation_cost, 0) AS amount'),
      'conditions' => array(
        'MONTH(date_ordered)' => $month,
        'YEAR(date_ordered)' => $year,
        'current_status' => 3
      )
    ));

    foreach($orders as $order) {
      $cost[$month] += $order[0]['amount'];
    }

    $month++;
  } // WHILE
} // FOREACH
```

So, this is working but very slowly (system from I am migrating this is working on plain PHP and SQL queries and doing fine) and I have 400+ users, and more than 1000 for each Order table.

What is the best way to make it happen in CakePHP style?

Comment: Maybe I dont described problem compleately. I need to get order sum grouped by months.

Comment: Is there some special reason for not using GROUP BY?

Comment: No there is no such a reason. I jsut don't know how to use it in such situation. Maybe you can give example how to do that? Thanks

Comment: There is a "group" key you can specify: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions. However, I would simply use the query() method of the Model with the SQL code of your old application.

Comment: I figured out the "group" key and used it, now I have only one query for all users (am using "IN" SQL key) and all months - it is awesome. Thank you. How can I accept your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution should be put as answer, not as comment. Otherwise this question will be marked as unanswered forever.

Anyway... this is what you need to do to group by:

```
$this->Order1->find('all', array(
  'recursive' => -1,
  'fields' => 'YOUR_FIELDS',
  'conditions' => 'YOUR_CONDITIONS',
  'group' => 'THE_FIELD_YOU_WANT_TO_USE_AS_GROUP'
));
```

The option group accepts an array so you can group by multiple fields.

For more complex queries: [book.cakephp.org/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions)